# Using R as a local server host

Tags: javascript, r

perhaps a bit of a basic question, im not sure. due to the complexity of my data (and the fact Im better with R than js), I have decided to use R as a "pre-processing" tool to generate a JSON file which can be used in d3.js for some viz work.

I wondered if anyone knows of a way I can use R as a local server to take the data and html file live. The other option would be to hard code in the data, but then its less of a tool and more of a one time visualisation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this what the shiny package is for?

Comment: i thought so too, but there seem to be some limitations to its usage. Ill keep looking at shiny if thats my only option!

Comment: I would suggest opencpu :  https://www.opencpu.org/

Comment: `servr` should be fine for this - see [here](https://github.com/yihui/servr/blob/master/README.md) for some basic usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[servr](https://github.com/yihui/servr) seems to fulfil your task exactly. It’s more general-purpose than Shiny.